# Qt FrameWork - Download video from vimeo, dailymotion

Tags: qt, video, download, vimeo, dailymotion-api

How i can download videos from vimeo or dailymotion using Qt FrameWork. Here is my code, but its not working:

```
downloadManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-1280x720/video/x5e553p.mp4?auth=1489424955-2562-4nmhj8lt-a840543181f17a50d614a6ff23ad5c07")); 

QSslConfiguration configSsl = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();    
configSsl.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
request.setSslConfiguration(configSsl);
replyn = downloadManager->get(request);
```

This url https://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/H264-1280x720/video/x5e553p.mp4?auth=1489424955-2562-4nmhj8lt-a840543181f17a50d614a6ff23ad5c07 redirect to https://proxy-058.dc3.dailymotion.com/video/793/580/326085397_mp4_h264_aac_hd.mp4?auth=1489259396-6658-s68i24c0-6b97977318a7dbd81ef264afc469ffa1#cell=core&hls_heuristic=1&hls_startFragPrefetch=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QNetworkAccessManager` does not handle HTTP redirection. You will have to handle it yourself by sending a new QNetworkRequest.

The new URL should be in the HTTP `Location` header. To get it you can use `QNetworkReply::header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader)`.

```
QUrl newUrl = replyn->header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader).toUrl();
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(newUrl);
...
```

Note that I have used `QVariant::toUrl()` to convert the QVariant to a QUrl, but you might need to convert the QVariant to a QString and then to an QUrl.

Comment: Have you tried something? It is just a matter of calling "downloadManager->get()" with the new URL.